# How to visualize independence?

Tags: probability

I have come across a question on independence. Please help me with how to visualize independence.

> We have a peculiar coin. When tossed twice, the first toss results in
>   Heads with probability $1/2$. However, the second toss always yields
>   the same result as the first toss. Thus the only possible outcomes for
>   a sequence of $2$ tosses are $HH$ and $TT$ and both have equal
>   probability. The two events $A = \{\textrm{Heads in the first toss}\}$
>   and $B = \{\textrm{Heads in the second toss}\}$ are independent ?

How can one conclude the possible outcomes for a sequence of $2$ tosses as $HH, TT$?
If they are independent or dependent, how do you prove them?

Comment: We are given that the second toss always yields the same esult s the first. If the first toss can only have outcomes H or T, this implies that two tosses can only have outcomes HH or TT.

Comment: A naive way of understanding independence is that two random variables are independent if knowing the value of one of them doesn’t give you any more information about the value of the other one. In this case, the value of one exactly determines the value of the other, so they are dependent. If you want to do it formally, two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \mathbb{P}(B)$. I think you should find it is pretty easy to show that this is not the case, here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ or, alternatively, $P(A|B)=P(A)$, that is the occurrence or non-occurrence of $B$ does not occur the chances of $A$ occurring.

In this case, it can easily be checked that $P(A \cap B) = \frac12 \neq \frac14 = P(A)P(B)$, that is, $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent.

Comment: How did you conclude $P(A \cap B) $ = 1 ?. Is it because the second toss always yields the same result as the first toss.

Comment: @s326280 I assume you mean $P(A|B)=1$. The question says "However, the second toss always yields the same result as the first toss.". If $A$ occurs, then $B$ must occur (and vice-versa). That is, $P(B|A)=1$. As $P(B)=\frac12$, A and B are dependent.

Comment: Pardom me for lack of understanding. I couldn't digest P(A/B) = 1 ? Can you add bit more explanation to it please? What i meant was  since the second toss always yields the same result as the first toss, so they have equal probability

For example. Event A = {1/2}, Event B = {1/2}(because of Event A) ,Then $(A \cap B)$ = {1/2}

Comment: No worries. Yes, the probability of A and B are each $\frac12$, but $P(A|B)$ means the probability of A if B happens. So basically, I know that B has already happened, and under that condition, I want to know the probability that A happens. Probability of A if B $=P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$. You might want to read a bit about conditional probability and independence of events from any probability text.